# How to edit Canon 7D RAW images in Photoshop CS2?

Tags: canon, raw, canon-7d, adobe-camera-raw

I upgraded the Camera Raw plugin to 3.7, which seems to be the latest available for Photoshop CS2, and it still won't open my Canon 7D RAW images. The error message:

> Could not complete your request because it is not the right kind of document.

Is there some way to make Photoshop CS2 read my images, or do I really have to [convert](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5794) several hundred GB of RAW to DNG?

Answer (score 4):

The support for the Canon 7D's RAW files was incorporated in [Camera Raw 5.6](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4621) and the latest version of Camera Raw supported by Photoshop CS2 is 3.7 so there are no support for the .cr2 files created by the 7D in CS2.

Unfortunately there is no way of opening these files in such an old version of Photoshop (unless there's a strange hack that I don't know of) and the only two options you have are upgrading or converting the RAW files to DNG format using the DNG converter.